# LibGDX on Raspberry Pi using JOGL - error on run

Tags: libgdx, raspberry-pi, jogl, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to run a LibGDX desktop app (a simple app displaying an image and nothing else) on Raspberry Pi 2 using the JOGL backend (https://github.com/gouessej/libgdx/).

In the current libgdx version, JoglApplicationConfiguration is abstract and there are 2 child classes: JoglAwtApplicationConfiguration and JoglNewtApplicationConfiguration.

When I'm trying to use JoglAwtApplicationConfiguration to run it, I'm getting an error:

```
 [java] glGetError 0x500
 [java] glGetError 0x500
 [java] JoglApplication: Couldn't initialize audio, disabling audio
 [java] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogamp.JoglApplicationBase.<init>(JoglApplicationBase.java:54)
 [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogamp.JoglNewtApplication.<init>(JoglNewtApplication.java:49)
 [java]     at com.mygdx.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:14)
 [java] Caused by: com.jogamp.openal.ALException: Error opening default OpenAL device
 [java]     at com.jogamp.openal.util.ALut.alutInit(ALut.java:69)
 [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogamp.audio.OpenALAudio.<clinit>(OpenALAudio.java:41)
 [java]     ... 3 more
 [java] AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackOSS_open: Could not open /dev/dsp: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
 [java] glGetError 0x500
 [java] Exception in thread "main-Animator#00" com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase$UncaughtAnimatorException: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught NoSuchFieldError: gl on thread main-Animator#00
 [java]     at com.jogamp.opengl.util.DefaultAnimatorImpl.display(DefaultAnimatorImpl.java:61)
 [java]     at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.display(AnimatorBase.java:451)
 [java]     at com.jogamp.opengl.util.Animator$MainLoop.run(Animator.java:198)
 [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
 [java] Caused by: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught NoSuchFieldError: gl on thread main-Animator#00
 [java]     at com.jogamp.opengl.GLException.newGLException(GLException.java:76)
 [java]     at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1311)
 [java]     at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1131)
 [java]     at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.display(GLWindow.java:680)
 [java]     at com.jogamp.opengl.util.DefaultAnimatorImpl.display(DefaultAnimatorImpl.java:54)
 [java]     ... 3 more
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: gl
 [java]     at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:21)
 [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogamp.JoglGraphicsBase.display(JoglGraphicsBase.java:164)
 [java]     at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:691)
 [java]     at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:673)
 [java]     at jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawableBase$2.run(GLAutoDrawableBase.java:442)
 [java]     at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1277)
 [java]     ... 6 more
 [java] EGLDisplayUtil.EGLDisplays: Shutdown (open: 1)
 [java] EGLDisplayUtil: Open EGL Display Connections: 1
 [java] EGLDisplayUtil: Open[0]: 0x1: EGLDisplayRef[0x1: refCnt 2]
```

While using JoglNewtApplicationConfiguration I get other error:

```
 [java] glGetError 0x500
 [java] glGetError 0x500
 [java] JoglApplication: Couldn't initialize audio, disabling audio
 [java] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogamp.JoglApplicationBase.<init>(JoglApplicationBase.java:54)
 [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogamp.JoglAwtApplication.<init>(JoglAwtApplication.java:49)
 [java]     at com.mygdx.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:16)
 [java] Caused by: com.jogamp.openal.ALException: Error opening default OpenAL device
 [java]     at com.jogamp.openal.util.ALut.alutInit(ALut.java:69)
 [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.bacAL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackOSS_open: Could not open /dev/dsp: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
 [java] kends.jogamp.audio.OpenALAudio.<clinit>(OpenALAudio.java:41)
 [java]     ... 3 more
 [java] Exception in thread "main" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Creating window failed
 [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogamp.JoglAwtApplication.<init>(JoglAwtApplication.java:103)
 [java]     at com.mygdx.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:16)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1272)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1247)
 [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogamp.JoglAwtApplication.<init>(JoglAwtApplication.java:101)
 [java]     ... 1 more
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jogamp.nativewindow.DefaultGraphicsConfiguration cannot be cast to com.jogamp.nativewindow.awt.AWTGraphicsConfiguration
 [java]     at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.chooseGraphicsConfiguration(GLCanvas.java:1557)
 [java]     at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.addNotify(GLCanvas.java:615)
 [java]     at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2769)
 [java]     at java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:770)
 [java]     at java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Frame.java:487)
 [java]     at java.awt.Window.pack(Window.java:807)
 [java]     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogamp.JoglAwtApplication$1.run(JoglAwtApplication.java:63)
 [java]     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:241)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Using both, the app builds fine but the error appears while I'm trying to run it.
Can someone help me?

My app code (generated using libgdx generator):

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

and the launcher class:

```
package com.mygdx.game.desktop;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogamp.*;
import com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame;

public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        JoglNewtApplicationConfiguration config = new JoglNewtApplicationConfiguration();
        new JoglNewtApplication(new MyGdxGame(), config);
        // OR:
        //JoglAwtApplicationConfiguration config = new JoglAwtApplicationConfiguration();
        //new JoglAwtApplication(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your source code somewhere (com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame??) or reproduce these issues with a simple example provided with LibGDX.

Comment: I've edited my post with code.

Comment: There is something broken in your environment as the "gl" field in Gdx isn't missing in my source code: https://github.com/gouessej/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Gdx.java#L36

Comment: I have never used the LibGDX generator, I cannot confirm that it works correctly with the JogAmp backend.

Comment: You can run com.badlogic.gdx.tests.jogl.JoglTestStarter to run the tests and as far as I know, it works.

Comment: What is missing? It's here: https://github.com/gouessej/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-jogamp/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/jogl/JoglTestStarter.java Unfortunately, as it uses Swing and AWT, I'm not sure it will work correctly on the Pi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If OpenAL fail to initialize
"AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackOSS_open: Could not open /dev/dsp: No such file or directory"
this originate from that the libopenal sound library,
failed to find your raspberry pi soundcard
then you have three options:

A) load the OSS linux kernel driver for the Pi's soundcard

```
sudo modprobe snd_pcm_oss
```

B) disable the OpenAL soft oss driver:
edit /etc/openal/alsoft.conf
and make sure that the drivers list contains -oss (it disables the OSS backend that tries to use the non existant dsp file)

C) The best solution would be if the OpenAL-soft project can detect that the OSS backend do not work and retry using its ALSA backend, however such a solution would require that someone collaborate and patch OpenAL-soft upstream to make OpenAl-soft work out of the box on the Raspberry Pi: http://kcat.strangesoft.net/openal.html

Comment: Thank you, modprobe helped for audio error but next errors (from JOGL) remains and app still doesn't launch.

Comment: Which version of JOGL 2 do you use with LibGDX? Don't mix AWT and NEWT. I'll try to reproduce your issues.

Comment: I don't store any GL instance into a field, one of your errors comes from com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.render.

Comment: Set JoglApplicationConfiguration.disableAudio to true if you don't need audio.

Comment: You don't use the same version of JOGL to build your program and to run it, it explains the NoSuchFieldError and maybe the ClassCastException. I'll update LibGDX very soon in order to use a more recent build of JOGL.

Comment: Your games main class should look like:

import    com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogamp.*;
     
     public class DesktopLauncher {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
       JoglNewtApplicationConfiguration config = new JoglNewtApplicationConfiguration();
       config.width = 1024;
       config.height = 550;
       config.title = "My Libgdx game";
                    new JoglNewtApplication(new LibGDXGame(), config);
      }
     }

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I'm using the same version of JOGL because I'm using ant to build and the run app.

Comment: LibGDX itself uses Maven and Gradle, look at pom.xml and build.gradle, there is a property called "jogamp.version". LibGDX doesn't use Ant.

Comment: @xranby Please can you use my repository on this example with a Raspberry Pi? https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-pax-britannica/blob/master/desktop/src/de/swagner/paxbritannica/desktop/DesktopLauncher.java I still have to install Debian on mine.

Comment: @gouessej this is how my repository looks when i use your repository with this example on the Raspberry Pi : https://github.com/xranby/libgdx-demo-pax-britannica/blob/gdx-backend-jogamp/desktop/src/de/swagner/paxbritannica/desktop/DesktopLauncher.java

Comment: @user3626048 The ClassCastException seems to come from a problem between AWT and X11, there is probably nothing to do to solve it. However, the NoSuchFieldError is caused by a problem in your settings. I've just updated my repository and it works correctly. It still uses JOGL 2.3.2-rc-20150812.

Comment: How can I run your examples on raspberry pi? When I try to build it using gradle it downloads libgdx jars from repository. How to use compiled before gdx on RPi (with arm natives)?

Comment: Xerxes succeeded in using LibGDX on the Pi with JOGL 2 in 2013: http://labb.zafena.se/?p=681 Please contact him on our official IRC channel to get some help: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=jogamp I don't see why you can't run the examples, I just follow the instructions in the official wiki and I replace the classes ****Application and ****ApplicationConfig like Xerxes does and it works.

Comment: I have tested to run libgdx on a raspberry pi 2 with JOGL 2.3.2 in 2015 as well you can try this build http://labb.zafena.se/jogamp/vc4/libgdx-demo-pax-britannica-1.6.3-armhf.jar  start it using     java -jar libgdx-demo-pax-britannica-1.6.3-armhf.jar

Comment: @xranby I've just tried your jar file and it's working. After some problem my project is running as well. I've exported runnable jar from Eclipse and it works on Raspberry Pi. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @gouessej also thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @xranby I have only one question - in your example game runs in window with title, close button in right top corner etc. My project (even empty one which displays only background) starts without it and keyboard isn't working (when button is pressed it shows symbols in command line terminal only but game doesn't detect it). It looks like it wasn't focused on window with libgdx game but on terminal.

Comment: The window with title, close button in right top corner etc was added in the JogAmp JOGL 2.3.2 release as part of the https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1178 enhancement. If you are using libgdx in combination with a version of JOGL such as 2.3.1 then only OpenGL rendered on top of the text mode is supported.

Comment: You need to change libgdx build.gradle line 8 at https://github.com/gouessej/libgdx/blob/master/build.gradle#L8  to use version 2.3.2-rc-20150929 ... the final jogamp jogl 2.3.2 release is imminent